# redirect to a page on a different server and post parameters to it

Tags: php

I am supposed to capture data from a form and send the data to  a url on a different server.For eg:-I have a form  on a page at the url http://www.form.com/register.php.
I capture all the data from this form and for some reason need this data to be processed on a page on another server at http://www.thereceivingpage.com/process.php.

As of now I am using headers to redirect with the parameters in the query  string something like this:-Header(Location:http://www.thereceivingpage.com/process.php?name=alice&address=a1&address2=a2) but I need to send a larger amount of data which wont happen as GET request. Can anyone suggest a better way where in I can post data rather than the data in the query string ...thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).  If you have to redirect to the site, it gets a bit trickier but you can still do it.  You can get the cookie and redirect information back from the site and then do a GET redirect using `header`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not update the action to simply post directly to that form?  Otherwise, you might want to look into something like curl: http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php

You'll pretty much re-use the header redirect syntax with the parameters but instead you'll tell it to be a post.

Answer (score 0):

> redirect to a page on a different server and post parameters to it

thanks to internet standards, that's impossible.

if it's third-party site, let user to interact with it directly. do not interfere between them, it smells

Answer (score 0):

If you want to develop secure applications then you should be aware that http://www.thereceivingpage.com/process.php is vulnerable to Cross-site Request Forgery (CSRF), meaning that anyone, from any site, can post form data to process.php.

process.php should be checking for a token (which www.thereceivingpage.com transmitted to the user as part of the form) and should be rejecting form submissions that don't contain the token to prevent submissions coming from anywhere but www.thereceivingpage.com and thus protecting your users from being manipulated into making requests they didn't want to.

In addition to your concern about the size of the GET requests you cause the client to make when redirecting, it's also not a good practice to turn POST requests into GET requests.

The best solution is to completely rethink the notion of delivering a form from one site to be submitted to a different site.

Answer (score -1):

You can manually set headers and send request or you can use curl

see this

http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/sending-post-form-data-with-php-curl.html